# Function return null

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

This function get data from API.
I don't understand its process.

Here the problem,

it returned **weatherModel** first and then it execute **onResponse** later.

It show in logcate **Log.d("data", "Here")** first

My function

```
 fun get(city: String?): WeatherModel? {

    var weatherModel: WeatherModel? = WeatherModel()
    val retrofit =
        retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Util.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    val service = retrofit.create(WeatherInterface::class.java)
    val call = service.searchCity(city!!, "metric", "789af9673b393eb97f2acdea022f2005")
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<WeatherModel> {

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<WeatherModel>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("data", "error ${t.message}")

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<WeatherModel>, response: Response<WeatherModel>) {
            Log.d("data", "success ${response.body()!!.weather!!.size}")
            weatherModel = response.body()
            data!!.getDataTrigger(weatherModel!!)
        }
    })
    Log.d("data", "Here")
    return weatherModel
}
```

So what is the problem?

Comment: call.enqueue is a asynchronous call, which means it doesn't run on main thread, that's the reason you will get Log.d("data", "Here") first.

Comment: It returns **null**, because your **API call** is asynchronous.

Comment: Why do you have so many `!!`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It show in logcate Log.d("data", "Here") first

`call.enqueue` is a asynchronous call, which means it doesn't run on main thread, that's the reason you will get `Log.d("data", "Here")` first.

This is the reason you are getting **null** returned

If you are using this method asynchronously or in some service and you want to execute synchronously then kindly use `call.execute` but this will only work if you are using in other thread apart from Main thread as network operation are not allowed on main thread, in this case this method wont return **null**.

Either you should use **live data** or an **interface** for the callback to receive WeatherModel.